# Digital Ocean Wordpress One Click Install how can we change the domain name after initial setup?

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean, oneclick

Digital Ocean Wordpress One-Click Install - I used different domain name while initial setup and once everything is ready and tested - I would like to change the domain name.

The apache sites-available has 000-default.conf which shows

ServerName $domain
ServerAlias www.$domain

Not sure if $domain is environment variable and how to change it properly as Once the domain name is changed - I also need to update SSL certificate.

It would be great if someone can direct me in the right direction